# How to loop over grouped data Payments and dates in Pyxirr library in XIRR function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, irr, xirr

I am trying to get XIRR for each customer with multiple entries with dates and payments in float.
I want to find XIRR for each customer by grouping them with Unique ID

Code I am trying

```
import pandas as pd

from pyxirr import xirr

result = df.groupby("ID")[["date","payment"]].apply(xirr)`
```

where df id my dataframe and ID, date and payment are my columns

I am getting error as
*InvalidPaymentsError: negative and positive payments are required*

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate XIRR, you need both positive and negative payments. This error means that some of the groups have only negative or only positive payments. You can suppress this exception by using `silent=True` parameter ([link](https://github.com/Anexen/pyxirr/issues/22)).

```
df.groupby("ID")[["date","payment"]].apply(xirr, silent=True)
```